# Release resource on boost::shared_ptr finalization

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

I do receive a shared_ptr from a library call, and pass it and some resource back into the library. The resource can only be deleted when the shared_ptr deletes its pointer:

```
std::ofstream* out = new std::ofstream(); 
...
shared_ptr<Lib::SomeClass> writer = Library.createWriter(out);

Library.appendWriter(writer);
```

The library expects me to manage out* but does not tell when it is safe to do so. Essentially, I want `out` to be deleted if `writer` is released.

Can this be achieved using the deleter facility of boost? Ideas?

Comment: Seems to me like the contract defined by the createWriter() API should specify who owns the input ofstream* and by implication how and when it gets released.  Either the library releases it, or you have to.  I don't see that encapsulating it in a shared_ptr helps, unless that's how createWriter() is defined.

Comment: They don't specify it, but from looking at their code I see that they expect me to own it. Unfortunately they do not tell me, when they no longer use it. That's why it thought waiting for the shared_ptr to be released might be a workable solution.

Comment: Unless the API takes in a shared_ptr<ofstream>, you are back to square one. What happens to the ofstream once it's handed to the library?  Is it apparent in the library code when it is no longer in use?  If you can correlate final ofstream usage to the API usage in your code, you may identify a reasonable point at which to assume you can clean up the stream.

Comment: As a side note: if the `Library` you're using resides in a separate module (.dll/.so) than your shared_ptr deleter should be the matching library call (`Library.releaseWriter(writer)` or similar), doing new/delete across module boundary is a very tricky business.

Comment: Thanks guys! So I have to negotiate with the library designer to change their interface (there is no releaseWriter or callback). I really would have thought that boost has a way to be notified of a shared_ptr being released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can do this directly with the shared_ptr API.

If Lib::SomeClass is an interface/abstract base class, you might be able to use a [Decorator](http://www.exciton.cs.rice.edu/javaresources/designpatterns/decoratorpattern.htm). The idea would be to define a class which subclasses `Lib::SomeClass`, contains a `shared_ptr<Lib::SomeClass>` and a `std::ofstream*`, and whose methods all forward to the corresponding method of the contained shared_ptr. The decorator's destructor, however, would delete the contained `ofstream` (or you could store it in some sort of RAII container like a `scoped_ptr`). So it would be an instance of the Decorator that you passed to appendWriter. Here's a sketch:

```
class SomeClassDecorator : public Lib::SomeClass
{
  public:
    SomeClassDecorator(shared_ptr<Lib::SomeClass> p, std::ofstream* stream)
      : p_(p), stream_(stream)
    {}

    virtual int MethodOfSomeClass(int x) {
        return p_->MethodOfSomeClass(x);
    }

  private:
    shared_ptr<Lib::SomeClass> p_;
    scoped_ptr<std::ofstream> stream_;
};

std::ofstream* out = new std::ofstream(); 
...
shared_ptr<Lib::SomeClass> writer = Library.createWriter(out);
shared_ptr<Lib::SomeClass> wrapper(new SomeClassDecorator(writer, out));

Library.appendWriter(wrapper);
```

Comment: Thanks! `writer` is indeed an interface, so this approach works nicely!

Answer (score 1):

You could try to create the output stream on the stack in a scope that is guaranteed to live longer than any reference to `writer`. It depends on your architecture, whether this is possible (although I would argue that in a good architecture it should be).

If you have the chance to negotiate with the library designer (as you mentioned in your comment), tell him/her to take the argument as a reference if that is sufficient. A `shared_ptr` should only be used if the ownership of the object is really shared.

Comment: Unfortunately, the API design is crooked here. The stack does not live long enough to see the end of writer being used.

Comment: @Christopher Oezbek: Well, some stack-frame has got to live at least as long as the last pointer. But I admit that it may even worse design to put the output stream somewhere where is doesn't belong just for that.